# "Selector invalid or missing!" when using jQuery Caption (Capty) plug-in

Tags: jquery, prestashop

I'm hitting my head over why I can't get this to work. I'm using the jQuery Capty plug-in.

> https://github.com/wbotelhos/capty

In prestashop I'm using this on `product-list.tpl`.

Including this on the top of the `product-list.tpl`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#animation').capty({
  animation: 'fade',
  speed:     400
});
</script>
```

This also in the file for the image within an a href.

```
 <img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'home_default')}" class="img-responsive" id="animation" alt="{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if isset($homeSize)} width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"{/if} />
```

The error I get is:

> Selector invalid or missing!

I can't seem to get it to work though. Any suggestions. I believe I am following the instructions but that's where I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I think that happens because you assign selector id="animation" in loop. So you get not uniq ID element in DOM. Let's try using class instead of id or init js-plugin for each of product images in the page, for example:

```
$('#animation_1, #animation_4, #animation_3').capty({...
```

and

```
<img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'home_default')}" class="img-responsive" id="animation_{$product.link_rewrite}" alt="{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if isset($homeSize)} width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"{/if} />
```

Comment: Hey Alexander, thanks for the response. :) I tried this exact solution but to no avail. Unfortunately I get the same response in the console. I'm not sure what else to try, is there anything else you think I should look into? Thanks!